# Insert multiple records issue (linq EF)

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-4, foreign-keys

I need to insert multiple records to different tables, the problem is that some tables have 2 different foreing keys and the EF throws me an exception. Part of my schema is shown below.
[image]

And this is my code

```
  Credito cred = new Credito()
            {
                Producto = credito.producto,
                Tipo = credito.tipo,
                Status = credito.status,
                Cantidad = credito.monto_prestamo,
                TasaInteres = credito.tasa_interes,
                Plazo = credito.plazo,
                Periodo = credito.periodo,
                FechaInicio = credito.fecha_inicio
            };
            Cuentas cuenta = new Cuentas()
            {
                IDCredito = credito.idCredito,
                IDBanco = credito.idBanco
            };
            Grupo gpo = new Grupo()
            {
                Nombre = credito.grupo,
                IDRepre = credito.idRepGpo
            };

            context.creditos.AddObject(cred);
            context.bancos_credito.AddObject(cuenta);
            for (int i = 0; i < credito.total_plazo; i++)
                context.amortizaciones.AddObject(AgregaAmortizacion(ref fechaPago, i, credito));
            context.grupos.AddObject(gpo);
            for (int i = 0; i < renglones; i++)
            {
                context.acreditados.AddObject(AgregaAcreditado(i, credito));
                context.agrupaciones.AddObject(AgregaAgrupacion(i, credito));
            }
            context.SaveChanges();
```

Everything but the "context.agrupaciones.AddObject(AgregaAgrupacion(i, credito))" is fine. The issue here is that "agrupaciones" has 2 FK (id_acreditado, id_grupo) even when I'm adding "grupos" and "acreditados" objects to context. 
Do you know what is happening? Does the entity framework is not capable of inserting FK from two tables withouth specifying the values?
Hope someone can help me, thanks

Comment: Can you post the exception message ?

Comment: Btw, what is "AgregaAgrupacion"?

Comment: @GianT971 AgregaAgrupacion is a function which gets data from array and returns an 'agrupaciones' type, is the same as "AgregaAcreditados". I have my visual studio in spanish but the translation of the exception would be something like this: "The main end of the relationship 'SACREDIModel.FK_agrupaciones_acreditados' can not be determined. It is possible that two or more entities have the same primary key"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the issue is you are only setting the FK id (IDRepre, IDBanco). Usually when setting references in EF you use the entire object (cuenta.Credito = cred;).

```
Credito cred = new Credito() 
        { 
            Producto = credito.producto, 
            Tipo = credito.tipo, 
            Status = credito.status, 
            Cantidad = credito.monto_prestamo, 
            TasaInteres = credito.tasa_interes, 
            Plazo = credito.plazo, 
            Periodo = credito.periodo, 
            FechaInicio = credito.fecha_inicio 
        };
Cuentas cuenta = new Cuentas()   
        {   
            IDCredito = credito.idCredito,   
            IDBanco = credito.idBanco   
        }; 
cred.Cuentas.Add(cuenta);
... (more mapping code here)
context.credito.AddObject(cred); 
context.SaveChanges();
```

You should only need to do "AddObject" for the parent object if the children are set correctly.

Comment: in fact i'm setting reference for all children except for "agrupaciones" which depends on "grupo" and "acreditados" that's why i'm adding "agrupaciones" object after "acreditados" and "grupos". If I comment "context.agrupaciones.AddObject(AgregaAgrupacion(i, credito));" line I get no problems

Comment: i would change that line to gpo.Agrupaciones.Add(AgregaAgrupacion(i, credito)); This gives it context to the grupos object is it related to.

Comment: If i get it right I should code the following: context.creditos.AddObject(cred);cred.bancos_credito.Add(cuenta);
for (int i = 0; i < credito.total_plazo; i++)
       cred.amortizaciones.Add(AgregaAmortizacion(ref fechaPago, i, credito));
                context.grupos.AddObject(gpo);
                for (int i = 0; i < renglones; i++)
                {context.acreditados.AddObject(AgregaAcreditado(i, credito));
                    gpo.agrupaciones.Add(AgregaAgrupacion(i, credito));
                }

Comment: creditos, acreditados and grupos are parent tables, however 'acreditados' depends on 'creditos'. How I should the framework work on this?

Comment: In that case you can set the relation the other way: acreditados.creditos = cred; acreditados.grupos = gpo; where acreditados is a new instance of the entity type.

Comment: sorry for the delay but your answer is completely accurate, thanks for your support